# Why does $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n }\frac{1}{i}$?

Tags: summation, algorithms

From [CLRS Problem 4.3, part 5](http://clrs.skanev.com/04/problems/03.html) .
Why does the following holds? $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n }\frac{1}{i}. $$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Sorry about that! I rephrased the question.

Comment: commutative law of addition

Comment: Jack, write the sums out for some small value of $n$, say $n=5$ or $n=7$. Trust me, you will see the light!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For change of indices, when it seems confusing I find it helpful to write out the first few terms, and if a finite sum, the last term or two, to see the pattern in the numbers as well as the variables.

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-i} = {1\over n-0} +  {1\over n-1} +{1\over n-2} +\cdots +{1\over n-(n-2)} +{1\over n-(n-1)}
$$

$$
={1\over n} +  {1\over n-1} +{1\over n-2} +\cdots +{1\over 2} +{1\over 1}
$$

$$
={1\over 1} +{1\over 2}  +\cdots + {1\over n-2} +  {1\over n-1} +{1\over n}
$$

$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{n }\frac{1}{i}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer to what seems like a simple question! I think there must be an error in the math linked in the question, which is what got me confused.

Comment: whichever answer you found the most helpful, (whether it's mine or not!) you should "accept" :)

Comment: why did I get downvoted?!

Answer (score 3):

One may perform the change of index
$$
k=n-i, \quad \text{new bounds:}\quad k=n-(n-1)=1,\quad k=n-0=n,
$$ giving
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-i} =\sum_{k=1}^{n }\frac{1}{k}.
$$ The latter sum is known as [an harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Thank you for your answer to what seems like a simple question! I think there must be an error in the math linked in the question, which is what got me confused.